# Conversion of long long to long double

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the first row of a long long matrix to long double, but when I print the result it only prints 0's. Here is the function:

```
void convertLLtoLD(long long **B, long double **C, int n){
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        C[0][i] = B[0][i]; //C[0][i] = (long double)B[0][i];
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%lf ", C[0][i]);
}
```

Here is the code where I allocate C that is done before calling the function:

```
long double** C = (long double**)malloc(n * sizeof(long double*));

for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
    C[i] = (long double*)malloc(n * sizeof(long double));
}
```

I'm compiling the code with GCC 4.8. B is read from a file and it's values are correct since I print them before I call the function. Even when I print them inside the function the result is the same. The result is also the same when I use a cast as in the comment. Can someone explain me why it isn't working?

Thanks

Comment: What values are you actually trying to convert?

Comment: `"%lf "` : use `"%Lf "` for `long double`.

Comment: In `convertLLtoLD(()`, you haven't declared any dimensionality for either B or C. They are both pointers to pointers to numbers, not pointers to rows or columns of numbers.

Comment: Your problem may lie here: `C[0][i] = B[0][i];`, Any value of `B[0][i]` less than `1` will become `0` in `C[0][i]`.

Comment: @Don'tYouWorryChild: Why is that?

Comment: Apparently your compiler missed `"%lf "` vs. `"%Lf "`.  The compiler warnings are not fully enabled.  Recommend enabling all warnings.  You will save time.

Comment: @sop : My mistake, I didn't notice that type of `C` is `long double**`. It is fine to write like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the statement :

```
printf("%lf ", C[0][i]);
```

You use an incorrect specifier (it expects a `double`).

Use `%Lf` to print a `long double`, use`%lld` to print a `long long`.

**Note:**

- In C++, just dont use `printf`, and prefer `std::cout` and the standard library
- [`printf` specifiers from en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: @mafso I was looking at it while typing, not sure its UB (looking at the std right now, but the en.cppref doc says its a `double`)

Comment: You're right, it's not UB, `l` is explicitly defined to have "no effect on a following a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G conversion specifier." (C99 7.19.6.1 p.7/C11 7.21.6.1 p.7).